# Non standard Algebraic Topology

Tags: reference-request, nonstandard-analysis, at.algebraic-topology, lo.logic

Let *$\mathbb R$ a field of non-standard real numbers (or any real closed field) equipped with its natural generalized metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. Equip *$\mathbb R^2$ and *$\mathbb R^3$ with the $\ell^1$-(generalized)-metric.

> **Question:** Does there exist an homeomorphism between *$\mathbb R^3$ and *$\mathbb R^2$?

Well, this is the simplest subquestion of the most general one

> **Question:** Is there anybody developing non standard Algebraic Topology? If not, is there any particular reason?

Thanks in advance,

Valerio

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the topology on ${}^*\mathbb R$ is just the order topology, generated by the open intervals? 

Note that the set $I$ of infinitesimals is clopen. So your question is equivalent to asking whether $I^2$ and I^3$ are homeomorphic. 

Comment: Yes, it is just the order topology.

Comment: See also this related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10870/which-topological-spaces-admit-a-nonstandard-metric Which topological spaces admit a nonstandard metric?

Comment: Valerio, it isn't really correct to speak of *the* nonstandard reals, since there are different nonstandard ordered fields each with the transfer principle (indeed, of any desired cardinality). Under the continuum hypothesis, then there is a unique saturated model of size continuum, and so one gets a little categoricity this way, but in general, one must deal with the possiblility of several different fields all looking like nonstandard reals. 

Comment: OK, thank you very much! So I should say *a field of nonstandard reals*.. but it is now not clear to me if the answer of my question may depend on the particular chosen field of nonstandard reals.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the comments, the actual topology on the non-standard extension can be quite nasty. This is illustrated for example in the first set of problems in [these notes](http://math.haifa.ac.il/kobi/o-minimal.pdf). A solution is to replace standard topological notions by *definable* analogues. Then things mostly work in an arbitrary o-minimal structure. This is also explained in the above notes.

More specifically on algebraic topology in the o-minimal settings, there are several papers by Berarducci and by Edmundo

Comment: Moshe, many thanks for the references.

Comment: Good references; see also, earlier, Delfs and Knebush in the semialgebraic case. We probably want to insist though on the fact that in placing ourselves in the o-minimal setting, the homeomorphisms that we are willing to consider are tremendously restricted compared to what was Valerio's original question. On the other hand, this is a setting that we actually **want** to consider, i.e. where developing topological methods actually led to some useful results.

Comment: Not sure about tremendously; it is true formally speaking, of course. But many natural expansions of the reals have been shown to be o-minimal, e.g., the exponential and all restricted analytic functions. So a substantial amount of functions and spaces that come up in nature are included.

Comment: @Moshe: I'd wager that there are more o-minimal expansions of the reals than what people originally expected when the theory took off. Nevertheless, it's still easy to get out of that framework, especially since combining two o-minimal structures can break o-minimality.

Answer (score 6):

Qu 2. In the 1970s there were some papers dealing with the non-standard analysis and the theory of shape in the sense of Borsuk. The author was Frank Wattenberg. The reference is Fund. Math. 98 (1978), 41-60.

I do not know if more was published although I did see a preprint of another paper.  I also do not know if those ideas have been followed up.

Comment: Tim, many thanks for the reference.

Comment: Wattenberg is Andreas Blass's "mathematical father" and my "mathematical grandfather".  It's great to see him mentioned! ;)