# Is homotopy definable by categorical means?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

Is being homotopic - as a relation between two continuous functions, i.e. morphisms in  **Top** - definable by categorical means? Can one detect from the context of dots and arrows, whether two parallel arrows in **Top** are homotopic to each other? Or from another ("higher") categorical point of view?

(If this were the case the relationship between **Top** and its quotient category [**hTop**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category) was purely categorical and not grounded on extra-categorical properties.)

Comment: This is close to a question of Daniel Miller: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92206/

Comment: @twimc: could you please give me the *slightest* hint why this is not a real question?

Comment: @HansStricker Have you take a look to this: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy .

Comment: Thanks to Tom and Giorgio: that gives me to study a lot!